# Pseudo element with attr background image

Tags: css

I have soome DIVs what should be empty and containt pseudo element AFTER width background source is getted from parent attribue.
Here is example:
the html

```
<div class="slide-image" href="#adad" data-src="some-src"></div>
```

the css

```
   .slide-image {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .slide-image:after {
        content: "";
        background-color: #c2c2c2;
        display: inline-block;
        color: red;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: attr(data-src url);
    }
```

I've tried many other ways, but can't make it work.

Comment: Using `attr()` as a value for anything other than `content` isn't supported by many browsers.

Comment: ...and there's really no reason to use it for anything else, since that's no improvement over inline CSS.

Comment: Do you mean that i can do this way only using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the DIV with fixed with and height. for example:

```
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <div class="slide-image" href="#adad" data-src="some-src"></div>
</div>
```

or give the .slide-image fixed with and height.

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SupY8/